# GNOME 3 "Always on top" keyboard shortcut not toggling off

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

This is not a big issue, but, a little annoying, and, above all intriguing.
I run a Debian 9 stable machine with Xfce 4.12 for a while, and I am setting up a GNOME desktop in parallel to try it out.

On Xfce I have a custom keyboard shortcut `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above` that has been working for ever toggling focused windows on top and on same level as others.

I tried the same one on GNOME 3.22 in System settings / Keyboard , I can only toggle the focused window on top of others, it does not toggle it back to same level as other windows. I have to right click the window's frame, and uncheck the "Always on top" option.

Does anyone have any idea why this could happen?

Comment: It was not a big issue ,so thanks for letting me know this does not affect only my system, and in that case, the workaround offered by 林果皞 seems like a good solution.

Comment: Please don't add [solved] to the title, instead  "accept" the answer you have found most useful (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to the answer) so others may more easily find it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this too at April 2016, my workaround is use 2 keys to toggle, e.g.:

```
wmctrl  -r :ACTIVE: -b add,above
wmctrl  -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,above
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, after a lot of research and working out how to write proper code in bash, I have created a single command that uses the wmctrl commands within a layer of logic to toggle the 'always on top' state effectively on the current GNOME desktop! Behold:

`bash -c 'wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b $([[ $(xprop -id $(xprop -root -f _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW 0x " \$0\\n" _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk "{print \$2}") _NET_WM_STATE) =~ "ABOVE" ]] && echo "remove" || echo "add"),above'`

It checks the active window state property "_NET_WM_STATE" using `xprops`, and if it contains the text "ABOVE" that means the 'always on top' option is active. Then it just runs the `wmctrl` command with the parameter `add` or `remove` as appropriate.

---

Command breakdown (each command is inserted into the next, replacing the `■` placeholder):

- Get active window id:

  `xprop -root -f _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW 0x " \$0\\n" _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk "{print \$2}"`
- Get the window state from xprop using the id:

  `xprop -id $(■) _NET_WM_STATE`
- Check if the state contains 'ABOVE', indicating that the window is set to 'always on top':

  `[[ $(■) =~ "ABOVE" ]]`
- Return "remove" if true, otherwise return "add":

  `■ && echo "remove" || echo "add"`
- run wmctrl command using the returned value as a parameter

  `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b $(■),above`
- Send the whole thing to `bash` so that you can use command substitution `${ ... }`, bash boolean evaluation `[[ ... ]]` and the regex match operator `=~`

  `bash -c '■'`

  This last step in particular took me a very long time to figure out. Until I realised that the keyboard shortcuts weren't running in bash by default, I had no idea why the commands were working in the console as I was testing them but silently failing when run directly as a keyboard shortcut. It drove me up the wall for ages!

Note: because you need quotes around the command you're sending to bash, I had to be careful when writing the command that I never went more than one more level deep (using double quotes). Any further nesting of strings in quotes would have required lots of confusing backslashes to escape the quotes.

Comment: You solved it ! Thanks.